# Understanding the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$

Tags: ring-theory

Can anyone please help me understand the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$

This is want I understand Let $I=(2,x^3+1)$

$I=(2,x^3+1)=(2)+(x^3+1)=2f(x)+[x^3+1]g(x)$ where $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x] $

So $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I=\{2f(x)+[x^3+1]g(x) +h(x)/h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}$. Hence if we assume $h(x)=x^4+5=x(x^3+1)+2(2)+1-x$ then we can say $I_{+h(x)}=I_{+(1-x)}$.

I read in a pdf that this ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$, but I cannot seem to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal in $R[X]$, then $J=I\cap R$ is an ideal in $R$, so we can consider the ring $R/J$, and $I/J$ is an ideal in $R[X]/J$, so that we can consider the quotient $$\frac{R[X]/
J}{I/J}.$$ One can show that this quotient ring is isomorphic to $R[X]/I$.

In your case, you can take $R=\mathbb Z$ and $I=(2,x^3+1)$. What is the intersection $R\cap I$?

Comment: $I\cap R$ will be constant polynomials over $R[x]$. I am confused does $I\cap R$ mean $I\cap R[x]$ which is $I$ itself.

Comment: $I\cap R$ means the intersection of $I$ with $R$, which is in general much smaller that $I$.

Comment: Yes, $I\cap R$ would be (2)